# GCE Instance won't recognize metadata (startup script)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am currently having a strange issue that I am hoping I can get some help with;

I am attempting to start GCE instances with a startup script that is being stored in Google Cloud Storage, and regardless of whether I attempt to launch the instance from the command line or the web UI, even though the config shows the appropriate metadata pair, the logs show "INFO No startup scripts found in metadata" and my startup script does not execute. See below screenshots.

I can see in my instance details that the metadata for the script URL exists.

[image]

But when I look in the logs, I get the following:

[image]

Anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 2):

Apologies; I figured out the problem.

`startup_script_url != startup-script-url`

Use hyphens, not underscores.